# overflow-x is not working when the overflowing table is placed inside another table

Tags: html, css

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <table width="100%" >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div width=100% style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll;" >
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I the above code I have with "apple" nested inside another table. I'm expecting a horizontal scroll bar when the content overflow. But I'm getting a scroll bar just below the table which cannot be scrolled. Instead I'm getting a scrollbar for the whole page.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, div doesn't have `width` attribute.

Secondly, you have to specify the `width`, 100% of what? Now it is not known. Give a specific `width` to this `div` or to it's some parent.

Look into my snippet.

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <table width="100%" >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll;width: 444px;" >
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                                <th> appleappleappleappleapple </th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there anyway I can make the overflow happen without setting the width to the some specific pixel value? Because the content in that table and the screen size varies.

Comment: @VikasNS you have to specify width, because browser have to know, when content starts to overflow. You can look on vw units (Equal to 1% of the width of the viewport's initial containing block.) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length